# Touch events are dropped in android

Tags: android, android-view

I am using FingerPaint example available in ApiDemos for drawing my finger movement on screen.

Now instead of line, I am adding circles in my path object and this path with circle will be drawn when onDraw method is called.

Now my issue is when I slowly move my finger it draws circles at the points given by [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) properly but when I move my finger with some speed, unlike line, it draws only few circles.

After debugging, I found that while moving finger rapidly, some of the touch events are dropped by the view and on that points circles are not drawn.

Can anyone give some pointers on this. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I can think of without seeing code.

First, are you getting the historical points recorded between touchEvents and using them also? If not, that would cause some serious jerkiness like you are talking about.

If you are, and it's just not picking them up, the best you'll be able to do might be to cheat it some. Check the distance between the current and last circle drawn. If it exceeds the circle's diameter too much, draw a line with the same thickness as the circle, with a circle on both ends.